# java - TCP - checking for data through functions

Tags: java, tcp

i am trying to periodically check for objects via a function in a tcp client.
i am able to successfully receive the object if i check for it in the function that makes the connection to the server, but if i attempt the same read using `gClient.getUpdate()`, i get a null pointer exception.
any advice is appreciated, thank you.

general program flow:

- main calls tcp client (server is running elsewhere)
- a loop in main continuously checks for a new object via a function in the client
- main updates an input mapping array based on the details of the new object

to clarify, getUpdate() is the function i wrote that checks for a new object

Comment: It's completely unclear what is going on here. In addition, this seems almost certain to be a specific problem with the questioner's code, rather than a question of general interest. Accordingly, i am voting to close. However, i encourage the questioner to post his code (actual code!) and his problem at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're forgetting to save a reference to an object inside your client, during the connection phase. I'm just guessing here; your question should contain more info about your problem, such as a code snippet or stack trace.